# Laplace's equation, separation of variables

Tags: laplacian

Ok so I have a question with tutorial solutions but there are a few points I don't understand.

Q: Find the solution to Laplace's equation  $$(∇^2)u=0$$ in the unit square $d=\{(x,y):0≤x≤1,0≤y≤1\}$ subject to the boundary conditions 
\begin{align*}
u&=0&\text{ on }x=0,x=1, \\
u&=\sinπx&\text{ on }  y=0, y=1.
\end{align*}

If someone could explain in detail all the steps that would be great! Mainly I don't understand how you know whether to use:

1. $λ=k^2>0$,   $F=Ae^{(kx)} + Be^{(-kx)}$
2. $λ=0$,  $F=Ax+B$
3. $λ=-k^2<0$,  $F=A\cos(kx) + B\sin(kx)$

and then why  $k=nπ$ making $λ=-n^2π^2$

then why we use form (1.) for G eqn

and then just generally solving for the solution

Comment: I just edited some mathjax to write your formulas readable. Still the question is hard to understand, since not everything you mention is defined (e.g. $λ, k, n$). And the last part is not a full sentence.

Comment: Do u know what is Laplace's equation?

Comment: that is how it is in the solutions. my notes give 1.-3. as possible forms to work out the solutions. By the last sentence i mean once you have put in the boundary conditions how do you solve for the solution to the equation..

Comment: and yes i know Laplace's. I understand separating into a function of x and a function of y, it is from the point of knowing which formula to use for F & G i do not understand

Comment: Is these conditions are true? $u(0,y)=0$, $u(1,y)=0$, $u(x,0)=\sin\pi x$, $u(x,1)=\sin\pi x$.

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: If $λ=0$, so $F=Ax+B$ and $F(0)=F(1)=0$ shows $A=B=0$ which is impossible!

Comment: In the case $λ=k^2>0$, then the assumption $F=Ae^{kx} + Be^{-kx}$ is a non-periodic function but $u(x,0)=F(x)G(0)=\sin\pi x$ says $F(x)$ is periodic, so this case in impossible also!

Comment: no no, we are using number 3 for F so λ=−k^2 <0

Comment: and number 1 for G. but i don't understand how you know what one to use. for if other questions like this come up

Comment: Am I right?....

Comment: and in the case $λ=-k^2<0$, then $F=A\cos kx + B\sin kx$ and from $u(0,y)=F(0)G(y)=0$ shows $A=0$ and $u(1,y)=F(1)G(y)=0$ shows $B\sin k=0$ says $k=n\pi$ (since $B\neq0$).